# Создание системы навигации в справочном приложении

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение-справочник. Структура понятна: в оглавлении есть несколько тем. В некоторых темах есть подтемы, в некоторых - сразу текст. В некоторых подтемах есть свои подтемы и т.д. В будущем возможно расширение тем. Есть куча более менее структурированного текста.

**Вопрос:** не могу понять, как грамотно организовать логику навигации внутри приложения. Как отслеживать текущую тему, клики переходов и возврата. Есть какой-нибудь способ/паттерн/библиотека, который помогает решать эту задачу? Где можно об этом почитать?

Настраивать каждый переход вручную считаю преступлением против основ программирования и здравого смысла. Как минимум потому, что такую структуру будет сложно менять.

Основные темы вынес в `NavigationDrawer`. А что дальше?

предпочитаемый язык - Java, но, если есть, рассмотрю аналоги с других языков.

[image: Структура справочника]

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: @RealKEK, спасибо, интересно! Почитал, понял в каком направлении думать.